# Java: upcasting Collection<T> to Collection<U super T>

Tags: java, generics, collections

I have a `Collection<T>`. I have a class TManager implementing an interface UManager which has a method `getCollection()` that needs to return a `Collection<U>` where U is an interface, and T is a class that implements U.

Aside from just casting it, e.g. `return (Collection<U>)Tcoll;`, is there a more correct way to handle this?

I control all 4 classes/interfaces here. Am I wrong in declaring `UManager.getCollection` as

```
public Collection<U> getCollection();
```

Should it be

```
public Collection<? extends U> getCollection()
```

?

Comment: Your code example is a bit confusing, do you want to return `U` or  `Collection<U>`? At least, the class/method must be instructed that T is an implementation of U.

Comment: Collection<U> --  my bad. I didn't type what I meant.

Comment: Another confusion, are `U` and `T` here actually the names of an interface and an implementing class or are they just generic types?

Comment: How did you end up with a Collection<T> in the first place? Can you have created that as a Collection<U> instead?

Comment: @BalusC: sorry, T and U are actual types, I should have used something like MyClass and MyInterface.

Comment: @Kevin B: I have a `Map<String, T> map;` hanging around, so I just want to return `map.values()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what you need to do with the Collection. If you don't need to put anything into the returned collection, then use the extends parameter

```
  public interface UInterface {

         Collection<? extends UInterface> getCollection();

  }
```

And be done with it. If in the future you do need to add to the collection, wrapping it in a new Collection and adding all does the job, ignore the performance for nothing hit of it (extra run time performance hit for a compile time issue).

If, however, the purpose is to return a mutable collection, then you can add a type parameter to your interface:

```
 public interface UInterface<T extends UInterface> {

        Collection<T> getCollection();

 }
```

Then your implementation would be:

```
 public class TClass implements UInterface<TClass> {

        pubic Collection<TClass> getCollection();

 }
```

The problem with this approach is that you absolutely must have a type parameter at runtime to use the interface to get a mutable collection out of it, or be referencing the concrete class.

Comment: Yes, this is an immutable collection. For mutable collections, I usually prefer passing the collection as an input parameter e.g. `public void getCollection(Collection<? super U> collection)`

Comment: Aha, and you can return a `Collection<TClass>` rather than `Collection<? extends UInterface>` because Java 5 supports covariant return types?

Comment: @Jason S, although Java 5 supports covariant return types, and this allows different return types based on generic parameters that are only possible because of covariant return types, this is not such a case. Collection<? extends U> and Collection<T> are not covariant, the Generic parameter is just erased at runtime. In this case it is the type parameter that lets you get it done.

Answer (score 2):

i believe you want:

```
public Collection<? extends U> getCollection();
```

You can find some official docs about this [here.](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/generics/)

@Jason, you're right.  The doc doesn't call out return types explictly, but it does work.  Here's an example method that demonstrates the syntax:

```
public Collection<? extends Throwable> getErrors() {
    return new ArrayList<Exception>();
}
```

Comment: @saleem: the link you posted doesn't go into detail about wildcards extending return types

Answer (score 2):

It should be:

```
public Collection<U> getCollection();
```

Try to [avoid bounded wildcards in return types](https://www.newt.com/java/effective-java-reloaded.pdf).

Subclasses would just declare the returned reference type as `Collection<U>` rather than `Collection<T>`.  That would eliminate your casts.

However, if you do see the need to have a bounded wildcard in the return type, then I guess you will have to return `Collection<? extends U>` and won't need the cast.

Comment: @notnoop: I did have Collection<U> and the compiler wouldn't let me return a Collection<T> without a cast.

Answer (score 1):

Your topicstart was a bit confusing because one-character identifiers are usually used by generic types but you explicitly mentioned about an interface and a class. So are you looking for something like this?

```
interface UManager<T extends UInterface> {
    Collection<T> getCollection();
}

class TManager implements UManager<TClass> {
    public Collection<TClass> getCollection() {
        return Arrays.asList(new TClass(), new TClass());
    }
}

interface UInterface {

}

class TClass implements UInterface {

}
```

Comment: Not really... I suppose I could use type parameters, but I'd rather not. Good point, though! (+1)